# How can I login to a Angular.io coded site using Nokogiri and Capybara/poltergeist?

Tags: ruby, capybara, nokogiri, mechanize, poltergeist

I am trying to login to a site for scraping purposes and it looks like they are using Angular.io. First I tried with Mechanize and logger without success so now I am using Capybara and Nokogiri.

This site's login webpage HTML code is:

```
<div _ngcontent-yhs-c14="" class="container">
  <div _ngcontent-yhs-c14="" class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
   <div _ngcontent-yhs-c14="" class="col-md-6 col-sm-11">
    <div _ngcontent-yhs-c14="" class="login-component">
     <h3 _ngcontent-yhs-c14=""><strong _ngcontent-yhs-c14="">Iniciar sesión</strong></h3><!---->
     <form _ngcontent-yhs-c14="" autocomplete="on" id="loginForm" novalidate="" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched">
      <div _ngcontent-yhs-c14="" class="form-group">
        <label _ngcontent-yhs-c14="" for="username">Correo electrónico:</label>
        <input _ngcontent-yhs-c14="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid is-invalid ng-touched" email="" name="user" ngmodel="" required="" type="email">
        <!---->
       <div _ngcontent-yhs-c14="" class="invalid-feedback ng-star-inserted">
          <!---->
          <div _ngcontent-yhs-c14="" class="ng-star-inserted"> El campo requerido. </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div _ngcontent-yhs-c14="" class="form-group">
        <label _ngcontent-yhs-c14="" for="pwd">Contraseña:</label>
        <input _ngcontent-yhs-c14="" autocomplete="off" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" name="pwd" ngmodel="" required="" type="password">
        <!---->
       </div>
      <div _ngcontent-yhs-c14="" class="contenedor_iniciar form-group d-flex ">
        <div _ngcontent-yhs-c14="" class="form-group login-footer">
         <p _ngcontent-yhs-c14="" class="info_accesos">Los datos de acceso son sensibles a mayúsculas y minúsculas.</p>
         <a _ngcontent-yhs-c14="" class="text-center-small btn btn-link p-0 "> ¿Olvidaste tu contraseña? <span _ngcontent-yhs-c14="" class="br"></span> Haga clic aquí para recuperar su acceso. 
         </a>
        </div>
        <input _ngcontent-yhs-c14="" class="btn btn-iniciar" type="submit" value="Ingresar" disabled="">
       </div>
     </form>
     <swal _ngcontent-yhs-c14="" input="email" inputplaceholder="Correo Electronico" title="Recupera tu contraseña" type="info"></swal>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I went through the "[Scraping data with Capybara](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/topics/scraping-with-capybara.html)" tutorial to try and login first, prior to trying to parse and started with this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'net/http'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

# get the HTML from the website
uri  = URI("http://letech.mx/login")
body = Net::HTTP.get(uri)

# pry at the bottom so we can play with it
require "pry"
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
binding.pry 

# The object we'll interact with
browser = Capybara.current_session

# Go to a web page (first request will take a bit)
url = "http://letech.mx/login"
browser.visit url

# Save the page locally, and open it (this is what Launchy does) 
browser.save_and_open_page
ls -v browser
browser.current_url

#fill the form with user and password and click on login button.
browser.fill_in 'user', with: 'user@email.com'
browser.fill_in 'pwd', with: 'password'
browser.click_on 'Ingresar'
```

When I do the last command `click_on`, I get the error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.top')
```

How do I get past the "login" window so I can start scraping?

Comment: Nokogiri has no direct involvement when logging in; It gets involved as an underpinning to Mechanize, or if you're scraping data. If the site uses DHTML, Mechanize and Nokogiri can't help until the page settles down and you can grab the entire rendered HTML and only a tool that supports interpreting/rendering JavaScript can help. I don't remember if Capybara can do that but WATIR tools can.

Comment: Also, be aware that Phantom.js is not under development anymore, so the tutorial and app are stale; You might do better finding something more active.